# Google translate setcookie("googtrans", "/en/ru", time()+3600, "/") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```
setcookie("googtrans", "/en/ru", time()+3600, "/");
```

I'am using this code to force the google translator, to translate a specific language, but it doesn't work, the dropdown list of languages appears in the page

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
  new google.translate.TranslateElement(
  {
      pageLanguage: 'ru',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT,
      autoDisplay: true
  },
  'google_translate_element'
  ); 
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working on my own page. The `pageLanguage` property should indicate the source language, not the target language. In your case, it should be `'en'` instead of `'ru'`.